# Rspec: How to I refactor tests that are similar? (example given)

Tags: rspec

I have 2 examples, but I feel like the majority of the code inside of them is the same. They are however, a bit different (the records are slightly different, and an additional assertion in the 2nd one too). I'm still a beginner at testing, so just looking for some tips as I go forward. I'm testing a rake task. Here's my code:

```
it 'leaves one billing info for each order' do
  order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)
  FactoryGirl.create_list(:billing_info, 2, order_id: order.id)

  expect(BillingInfo.all.count).to eq(2)

  run_rake_task

  expect(BillingInfo.all.count).to eq(1)
end

it 'keeps the billing info with trevance information' do
  order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)
  FactoryGirl.create(:billing_info, order_id: order.id, complete_trevance_message: nil, trevance_attempts: nil)
  FactoryGirl.create(:billing_info, order_id: order.id, complete_trevance_message: "303 -- Processor Decline", trevance_attempts: 1)

  expect(BillingInfo.all.count).to eq(2)

  run_rake_task

  expect(BillingInfo.all.count).to eq(1)
  expect(BillingInfo.first.complete_trevance_message).to eq("303 -- Processor Decline")
end
```

As you can see, they are really similar. Is it okay to split these up into two like this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion DRY isn't always the best rule in tests. It often means that you have to hide some code in method so this is harder to read etc. So I woudn't change much, but there are some things that can be done in simpler way.

```
context "billing rake task"
  let(:order) { FactoryGirl.create(:order) }

  it 'leaves one billing info for each order' do
    FactoryGirl.create_list(:billing_info, 2, order_id: order.id)
    expect { run_rake_task }.to change { BillingInfo.count }.by(-1)
  end

  it 'keeps the billing info with trevance information' do
    FactoryGirl.create(:billing_info, order_id: order.id, complete_trevance_message: nil, trevance_attempts: nil)
    FactoryGirl.create(:billing_info, order_id: order.id, complete_trevance_message: "303 -- Processor Decline", trevance_attempts: 1)

    expect { run_rake_task }.to change { BillingInfo.count }.by(-1)
    expect(BillingInfo.first.complete_trevance_message).to eq("303 -- Processor Decline")
  end
end
```

Notice that this changes spec a little bit, so you don't check if count changed from exactly 2  to exactly one, but that it changed to 1 less. I think that here it is better, but I can't be sure as I don't know your application well.

Comment: @Edmund - While the point about DRY and tests is well taken, you might want to check out https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group for future if not current reference. Implementing that unique final expectation in the second case would be tricky and probably not worth the approach, but the rest is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor to something like this:

```
let(:order) { FactoryGirl.create(:order) }

describe "description here" do

  before do
    FactoryGirl.create_list(:billing_info, 2, order_id: order.id)  
  end

  it 'leaves one billing info for each order' do
    expect(BillingInfo.all.count).to eq(2)

    run_rake_task  

    expect(BillingInfo.all.count).to eq(1)
  end

end

describe "description here" do

  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:billing_info, order_id: order.id, complete_trevance_message: nil, trevance_attempts: nil)
    FactoryGirl.create(:billing_info, order_id: order.id, complete_trevance_message: "303 -- Processor Decline", trevance_attempts: 1)
  end

  it 'keeps the billing info with trevance information' do
    expect(BillingInfo.all.count).to eq(2)

    run_rake_task

    expect(BillingInfo.all.count).to eq(1)
    expect(BillingInfo.first.complete_trevance_message).to eq("303 -- Processor Decline")
  end

end
```

The `before` hook will give you more flexibility in the future in your need.